# How to center jquery Dialog box in IE compatibility mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I created a jquery dialog box which works fine in IE when not in compatibility mode.  However, my company requires IE's compatibility mode usage for some legacy code.  Below is what I have thus far.  Any ideas on how I can change it so that it will display in the center while using iE compatibility?

```
var originalColor;

function Form2958MessageBox(isValid) {
    var target = $(this);
    if (isValid) {
        $("#Form2958DataGridSuccess").dialog({
            position: { my: "center", at: "center"},
            title: "Successful Submission!",
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("destroy");
                }
            } 
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#Form2958DataGridFailure").dialog({
            position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: target},
            title: "Submission Errors Found",
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(".ui-dialog-title").css("color", originalColor);
                    $(this).dialog("destroy");
                }
            },
            create: function (e, u) {
                originalColor = $(".ui-dialog-title").css("color");
                $(".ui-dialog-title").css("color", "red");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE Compatibility mode (IE7 emulation) emulates IE7 and lower and does not recognize the auto rule for the css margin property.

you can add an align attribute to the div to allow it to gracefully fallback.

<div align="center" style="margin:0 auto;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">

you may have to specify the text alignment rules also (as above);

Your page will probably not validate at validator.w3.org, but you can safely ignore the warning/error.

or

You can add the x-ua IE=Edge meta to your page to force any IE7 browsers or any users who still may be using IE8 and 'display all sites in compatibility view' to force IE8+ rendering and css 2.1 compliance. Use the x-ua meta if your site is an intranet site and you have enforced 'display intranet sites in compatibility view'.

IE7 emulation also doesn't support static positioning.....your div overlay should be positioned absolutely or relative; the workaround for static positioning in IE7 emulation is to use the MSIE calc rule on a .static class.

Regards.